# Tough Bash UDP issue

Tags: bash, udp

Has anyone  ever looked into forming and sending test UDP packets from Bash? I need to test some UDP ports in addition to TCP ports in a piece of code. TCP is easy since its connection oriented. UDP on the other hand is a little more challenging. I would assume the packet would have to be built and sent out, then bash would have to wait for a reply, or timeout to determine if the port is open on the other end. Other utilities can be used, however I'd like to try to avoid it since it was so easy to do straight with Bash for TCP. Any thought on how to do this? The goal is a port check tool to monitor servers. Yes there are other tools out there like NMAP, but I don't need a complex port scanner.

*** UPDATE ***

Took Barmar's suggestion and tried using netcat, but I cant get it to work with UDP. The terminal just gets stuck whenever I try UDP:

```
 netcat -uvz 8.8.8.8 53
```

This doesnt work either and this is a straight example from Google

```
nc -vnzu server.ip.address.here 1-65535 > udp-scan-results.txt
```

*** UPDATE ***

For those who say "you can't do that with netcat", can you explain why all these people say you can? Whats the deal netcat...

```
http://www.radarearth.com/content/using-netcat-udp-port-troubleshooting
https://gist.github.com/benhosmer/2429640
http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/04/nc-command-examples/
```

*** UPDATE ***

Here is yet another:

```
http://mikeberggren.com/post/16433061724/netcat
```

*** UPDATE ***

And here is some other evidence that contradicts everything above... sigh

Very bottom of page, under "Caveats"

```
http://linux.die.net/man/1/nc
```

*** SOLUTION ***

This ultimately helped me understand my own logic. Hopefully it will help others out there too.

```
http://serverfault.com/questions/416205/testing-udp-port-connectivity
```

Comment: The `-u` option to `netcat` tells it to use UDP instead of TCP.

Comment: And if you google "udp netcat" you'll find webpages showing how to use it.

Comment: I didn't want to use another utility if I could avoid it, but Netcat seems really simple. Only problem is, I cant seem to get it to work with UDP. Why does this fail? netcat -uvz 8.8.8.8 53

Comment: If you were doing TCP instead of UDP, wouldn't you use `netcat` as well? Or are you talking about `/dev/tcp/host/port`? If so, `bash` also has `/dev/udp/host/port`. Regarding `netcat -uvz`, that can't work with UDP -- UDP doesn't have connections, so there's no way to test a port without sending something to it.

Comment: Yes I will use netcat for both if it works for both. I understand UDP is connectionless. That was my original question. I couldn't think of a way to implement it, being that you dont get a response. As for the netcat command line. That ussage is straight off of several sites on google specifically saying you can do that with netcat for UDP so I dont know why you say it cant be done. I can probably cite 5+ websites that show using the exact same command line options testing a DNS server over UDP and saying it works.

Comment: I don't see how `-z` can work with UDP. The man page specifically says that it doesn't send anything. If you don't send something, there's no way to tell whether the port is open. I think it may be the common Internet phenomenon: someone wrote something without testing, and everyone else just copied it without verification (take a look at the first two hits: the filenames in their example command lines are the same).

Answer (score 0):

There are different tools that allow for sending UDP packets, e.g. [`hping`](http://www.hping.org/) and [`nmap`](http://www.nmap.org/).

```
hping host.example.com --udp -V -p 53
nmap -sU -p 53 host.example.com
```

However, unlike TCP UDP does not establish a connection, i.e. you're don't automatically get a response.

Comment: Yes I understand UDP is connectionless. That was my original question. I couldn't think of a way to implement it, being that you dont get a response.